# Avoiding redeclaration for header to source file

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two files foo.h and foo.cpp

**foo.h**

```
class foo
{
    public:
        Foo(); 
        ~Foo(); 
    private:
        /*
        Member functions
        */
        static void DoThis();
        /*
        Member variables
        */
        static int x;


    protected:  
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo::x;

void foo::DoThis()
{
    x++;
}
```

Can I avoid the hassle of having to declare each variable in foo.cpp again? If I removed this line `int foo::x;` I would get a linker error for unresolved external symbol.

Is there another way of doing this without having to type a line for each variable I'm planning to use?

Comment: You are not declaring anything in your implementation-file (.cpp). You are defining things there. And no, a definition is not optional. (You could make the functions definition inline, if you wanted.) Aside: Use proper include-guards in the header-file to guard against being included multiple times.

Comment: `static int& GetX() { static int x = 0; return x; }` in the header. Remember compilers work faster when there is less bloat in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to re-declare static variables. If you make a variable in the class definition without making them static, you can just leave them there. Example:

foo.h

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

class Foo{
private:
  static int i; //Static variable shared among all instances
  int o; //Non-static variable remains unique among all instances
public:
  Foo(); //Consructor
};

#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
int Foo::i = 0; //Only static variables can be initialized when in a class
//No definition required for non-statics

Foo::Foo(){
  //Constructor code here
  i = 0;
};
```

The #ifndef block prevents the header from accidentally being included multiple times by the same source file. This is in case a header is included in another header, which, if these blocks are not present, could result in an infinite include loop and force the compiler to quit when it counts an include depth that's too high.

Comment: The header guards also prevent multiple definition errors